# I want to get only one back slash in nsmutable array

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I want to get only one back slash "\" when string passed in array, but it gives me two "\\" back slash you can see the result below:

```
var arr = NSMutableArray()
let myText = "2018\\/04\\/16"
print(myText, "String result is proper")
arr = [myText]
print(arr, "Array result not proper")
```

This is my result of console:

```
2018\/04\/16 String result is proper

("2018\\/04\\/16") Array result not proper
```

I want to get only "2018/04/16" when I print(arr) that is my array result

Comment: Why you using backslash??? Remove it & it works perfectly.

Comment: I'd say that the prints show two backslashes to notify the that there are two (you need one to allow the second backslash to be "visible"). That's debug stuff. Also if you use Swift 3+, prefers Array, not NSStuff like NSMutableArray.

Comment: I m not sure what you asked. But your question is that you want to remove \\ from the string right.?

Comment: The console output was rendered as HTML and therefore did not display the actual output. I fixed that.

Comment: My guess is that your string is fine and has a single backslash. `print` probably shows the escaped string when printing out an array for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have updated your code. Please try this(You do not need extra slash)

```
var arr = NSMutableArray()
let myText = "2018/04/16"
print(myText, "String result is proper")
arr = [myText]
print(arr, "Array result not proper")
```

> Please check value.. its like that you want:
>   [image]